# Sql - how to make sure one admin account in database will not get deleted

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have `tblUserAccounts` with columns `Username`, `Password`, and `UserLevel`. It currently have only one row with Admin UserLevel. And in my C# program, only admin accounts can update / delete accounts. How can I prevent someone to delete all rows from `tblUserAccounts` and make sure there's always at least one Admin account? Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C# application probably there is a form where you should edit/delete your users so just before load check if user is Administrator, if not show him a message or completly hide form for those who are not Administrators (in UserLevel tbl) and after that/or you could set extra field in database (tblUserAccounts) for your MAIN administrator, for example lets call that field "IsMain" type BIT and set:

`IsMain = true`,

and if someone want to see all users or whatever just load him users with status

`IsMain=false`

so you will allways have one administrator "protected" somewhere there because you set true to only one user and you are loading / showing users with status = false :)  :)